# In this circuit, the light intensity sensor (LDR) only senses 3_2 cm. How can I improve the sensitivity of this sensor to reach 1m?

Tags: sensor, photoresistor, security, photosensor

In this circuit, the light intensity sensor (LDR) only senses 3_2 cm. How can I improve the sensitivity of this sensor to reach 1m?

https://ibb.co/c3X1NRS

[image]

Comment: I have an electronic security eye circuit. The circuit’s work depends on the light intensity sensor (LDR), but this sensor is sensitive to near light only, so what should I do to make this sensor sensitive more and stronger to light and for a further distance, it was at a distance of 1 meter, should I change  Something in the circuit or should I do something for the sensor?  I would be grateful for your advice and comments on this matter

Comment: Use a brighter light.

Comment: Use a lens to focus the lught.

Comment: An LDR doesn't sense distance, it senses light intensity.

Comment: @ForkanXa How does an electronic security eye work? What does it do exactly?

Comment: Lens is a good solution.

Comment: @Forkan You should put the extra details into your question by **editing** it rather than adding comments.

Answer (score 1):

An LDR senses light, not distance. I guess you want to make a light beam consisting of a light and an LDR, so you can detect when something blocks the light from getting to the LDR.

An LDR can only sense the total light that reaches it, not the direction. And like you discovered, your light is going to be swamped out by ambient light. You can make the light brighter, or cut down the ambient light.

Imagine the LDR was your eyeball. How would you block out ambient light? One way is to look through a straw. Another way is to use a magnifying lens. A magnifying lens will block out ambient light and also make the light bigger so you can see it more easily. Either of those work for light beam systems too. Professional ones probably use lenses but you can just aim a straw in the right direction.

If you choose to use a straw make sure to use a black straw so the sides of the straw don't contribute light (which is bounced ambient light).